# How to position elements independently using Stack, Row, and similar elements in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, css-position, positioning

I have been trying to replicate these two designs in Flutter using Stack, Positioned, Row, and similar related widgets, however, I've been getting stuck in the same stages again and again. I either can't center the text or cannot position the back button correctly. Also, I am trying not to use fixed sizes/positions as this is supposed to be somewhat adaptable to different screen sizes.
Could someone point me in the right direction, of how to create this or similar layouts, which would be reused in other screens?

Example 1:

[image: Example 1.]

Example 2:

[image: Example 2.]

Comment: Did you try to use the Appbar widget? It already manages a back button.

Comment: I could not get the border underneath and behind the app bar in this case. Otherwise I would've used the app bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example numero 1, I came with this solution:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFF0B2746),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18),
                      child: Text(
                        'Glossary',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Card(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                    ),
                    elevation: 6,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the result is the following:

[image: Example Number 1]

For your second example, I had to add extra logic:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFF0B2746),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 64.0,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 54, right: 8, top: 8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Icon(Icons.train, size: 35),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18),
                            child: Text(
                              'Metro',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, size: 35),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        )),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Card(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                    ),
                    elevation: 6,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the result for this one is the follwing:

[image: Example Number 2]

Comment: Thank you!! From what I can see, I was using the stack widget incorrectly. Really helpful, and well structured. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad that helped. Takes time but it starts to become getting easier using colums and rows. Stack is also challenging if the root one is expanded and you need fixed sizes for their children.